# Apache is downloading fcgi

Tags: apache, unix, fastcgi, redmine

I'm trying to run my redmine on apache2, meanwhile i haven't touch in apache for years and all documentation seems somewhat outdated.

Anyway, I've setup all the config files but when i try to open redmine my apache downloads the fcgi instead.

this is my redmine.conf

```
Alias /redmine /path/redmine/public

<Directory /path/redmine/public>
    AddHandler fastcgi-script fcgi
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride all
    Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi
</Directory>
```

what am I missing?

the url im trying to open is http://localhost/redmine

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have enabled AllowOverride All in your configuration.
If you don't know what that is then please check here and try again afterwards. 
[Enabling use of Apache .htaccess files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles)

```
<Directory /your/path>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

**Restart your webserver:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

**If this is enabled then please try this:**

> First change the sources.list and create a file preferences, so that I
>   can install pinning versions from the testing branch.

```
#  /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates  main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
```

> Create this file

```
#  /etc/apt/preferences

Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian,a=testing
Pin-Priority: 850

Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian,a=stable
Pin-Priority: 990

Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian
Pin-Priority: -1
```

> And already the installation of Redmine can start from the testing branch

```
apt-get update
apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql libsvn-ruby ruby-rmagick libfcgi-ruby1.8 -t=testing
```

> This is then the configuration file!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName redmine.DOMAIN
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/redmine/public/
    AddHandler fcgid-script fcgi
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/www/DOMAIN/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/DOMAIN/access.log combined
    <Directory /usr/share/redmine/public/>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews +ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: is it possible there something wrong with my fcgi file? causing it to be downloaded

Comment: @NavySeal I’d have to take a look at that.